# Errors retrieving packages from raspbian.org

Tags: apt

Trying to install hostapd with apt-get fails with a 404 error "Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/w/wpa/hostapd_2.3-1+deb8u4_armhf.deb
When I go to the link and look, the filename is hostapd_2.3-1+deb8u5_armhf.deb
How can I get the file to download and install?
Also tried to run apt-get dist-upgrade and many 404 failures there as well.
What to do?

Comment: `apt-get dist-update` isn't a supported apt option. Did you mean to say either `apt-get update` or `apt-get dist-upgrade`? You might like to [edit] to clarify that. I would guess that you particularly want `update`, not `dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Edited to correct to apt-get dist-upgrade.  I had already run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade.  Just performed a full clean install and still have the same problem trying to get the hostapd from the "official" repo.

Comment: Try downloading the `.deb` directly, then run `apt install /path/to/downloaded/package.deb`. I wonder if the repo hasn't been updated properly — if so, just downloading it manually should work.